# Plotting HeatMap using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, heatmap

I am working on a localisation problem of object detection. I got the coordinates of rectangular boxes in different frames of video. So my numpy array looks like this--

[[403 172 614 326]
 [345 153 652 383]
 [345 172 537 326]
 ...
 [134 115 326 307]
 [153  57 403 307]
 [191  19 479 230]]

Here 4 values in each column are x1, y1, x2, y2 which are basically coordinates of rectangular box defined as--

```
    __________________(x2,y2)
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    _(x1,y1)__________
```

(x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are coordinates of the rectangular localised box as shown.
 Frame size (taken from a video) is constant. It is 480 * 850.
I need to plot heat map for these values, saying pixels which are occupied by more no. of boxes need to be more bright.
 [Sample Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH6sr.png)

Basically, this is not a normal heatmap (plotting of 2d array based on its value).
Can anyone suggest how to obtain heatmaps in this way?

Comment: So you need to establish how many boxes are in each pixel, and then plot a 2D heatmap that refers to that count as the z value. It's best to share the code that you tried and what it's not doing correctly.

Comment: @mauve I got required heatmap. Thanks for showing your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an array `M` of length `n`. Each element of `M`, say the first element `M[0]`, is a four-element array `[x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2]` that defines a box in a larger space. Then, these boxes can be overlapping, and you want the heat map that is produced by the total combination/layering of all these boxes.

I'll start by generating some random data:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.random.randint(0, high=500, size=(50,4))
```

Then, we initialize an empty matrix (I am assuming here it the resulting heat map has dimensions 500x500 based on the sample data you provided, but you can adjust as appropriate):

```
R = np.zeros((500,500))
```

Then, for each entry in the input array of arrays, we fill-in the corresponding square by adding 1 to each "pixel" that is covered by the square's dimensions:

```
for row in M:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = row
    for x in range(x1,x2+1):
        for y in range(y1,y2+1):
            R[x,y] += 1
```

Finally, we can plot the resulting heatmap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(R)
plt.show()
```

Which will give us a heat map with overlapping boxes, as desired:
[image: Resulting heatmap]

Comment: Yep, I got required plot. Thanks a lot :)